# Excel found unreadable content in workspace.xlsx (POI - java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a workbook from java code.
I'm using POI library for this, after executing the program,
workbook is successfully creating in my directory, But when i'm trying open my excel file im getting error like "Excel found unreadable content in workspace.xlsx".

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              System.out.println("failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

I'm using excel 2010.

Comment: You don't add any content to you workbook, so maybe thats a required part of a valid Excel document. And in your code you save the document as `xls` instead of `xlsx`. That might be confusing Excel.

Comment: Hi @MichaëlHompus, Thanks for your reply. I tried both formats xls and xlsx. But not working,

Comment: What does the POI library documentation say about creating workbooks? Are you sure that the version of that library "works" with your version of Excel?

Comment: Hi @EddyG, I read the documentation, POI library supports excel 2010 which i'm currently using. Problem was solved from the below answer. Thanks for your reply,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is making two mistakes - no sheets (not valid), and wrong extension (XSSFWorkbook = .xlsx)

To create a new empty Excel xlsx file, your code should instead be something like:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
wb.createSheet();
FileOutputStream fileOut;
try {
     fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
     wb.write(fileOut);
     fileOut.close();
     System.out.println("success");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new RuntimeException("failure", e);
 }
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly this but I'm getting `Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content`

Comment: @Ariel Without your code, and without details of which parts of the file Excel fixed, and without the POI version, there's not a lot anyone can help you with... You're best off posting a new question with all those details in!